# Call a function with a single character in Python

Tags: python, function, spyder

If I have a function that computes the factorial of a number, is there any way that this function can be called with the character '!' ?

Essentially, I would like to type

```
In [1]: 5!
```

and receive:

```
120
```

I am using Python 3.5 with the Spyder IDE.

Comment: no, you can't. You had to rewrite Python to add new syntax.

Comment: No. That is a syntax error.

Comment: A function calculating the factorial of a number must receive a *number*. The `!` would mean that you'd need to use a *string* (e.g. `"5!"`) to avoid a syntax error.

Comment: @ray no, quotes would make it a string

Comment: @jonrsharpe You're right. I clarified what I meant. I was assuming that something else would've been done already to avoid a crash (e.g. adding the quotes), since writing `5!` would just raise an exception.

Comment: The only operators you can override in Python are the [built-in ones](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
from math import factorial

input_string = "5!"

def is_int(input_string):
 try:
  int(input_string[:-1])
  return True
 except ValueError:
  return False

if input_string[-1] == "!" and is_int(input_string):
 print(factorial(int(input_string[:-1])))
```

This is not exactly you want but it looks like closest solution
This code formatted for python 2.7